# Word for “puts pressure” around an object (intransitive verb)

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> The noose around his neck ________ even more.

or

> The noose around his neck increasingly ________.

*Compresses* perfectly conveys the meaning of exerting pressure, however, it is a transitive verb and would not fit in any of the sentences. Same for *constricts*.

*Smothers* is not what I'm looking for because it’s limited to the example of a noose but I want a word that would work more generally, e.g., in the case of a handcuff around a wrist.

*Tightens* is the best word I could think of. However, it doesn’t perfectly convey the meaning of exerting pressure, because, in this case, it would be  reflexive (the noose tightens — the noose is both the subject and implied object of the action), while I prefer a word which clearly implies that the pressure is being put on the neck or wrist.

Comment: Go for the Thesaurus--confined, constricted, limited,

Comment: I don't understand your objection to *constricted* in your examples. Are you familiar with [constrictor knots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrictor_knot)?

Comment: @PhilSweet "The noose tightens" definitely sounds better than "The noose constricts."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Tightens* is the most appropriate word. The intended connotation can be achieved by rephrasing the sentence as follows.

> The noose (increasingly) tightens around his neck.

Following "tightens" immediately by "around his neck" emphasizes the pressure exerted by the noose on the neck.

Comment: The OP has already rejected the word *tightens* for some reasons, even though it was the best word he could think of! I think better for him to rephrase the whole sentence with some transitive verbs like *press, compress, constrict, squeeze etc*.

Comment: @mahmudkoya I am the OP! I was thinking and searching for words for about an hour until I settled on this. I posted the answer as SE recommends for others who might be faced with the same question in the future.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting! Then, why can't you think of using an appropriate transitive verb?

Comment: @mahmudkoya I'm translating to English. In the original language, a word is used which means "exerts pressure" as an intransitive verb.